# IntelliJ can't find Maven dependencies at runtime

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm not getting any red lines, but IntelliJ can't find my Maven dependencies when I run the (Play) app. Tried `invalidate cache/restart`. Tried running `mvn clean install`.

**compiler error message**

```
(compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources and 5 Java sources to /Users/****/IdeaProjects/GeoMood/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/****/IdeaProjects/GeoMood/app/views/show_tweets.scala.html:1: not found: value twitter4j
[error] @import twitter4j.Status
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>geomood</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0,)</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why IntelliJ isn't picking this up? The maven build runs fine, and the dependencies are listed under external libraries.

Comment: Can you check if you can run the app from command line?

Comment: Try also enable *Don't compile the project within IDEA before run* in Settings (Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | Play2 settings or enable Play2 compiler there.

Answer (score 3):

I usually have to do the following to make IntelliJ aware of changes to my dependencies in the pom.xml:

1. Right click the root folder of the project in IntelliJ's project view
2. Go the the Maven menu item, and open the Maven submenu
3. Click Reimport
   [image: Maven popup menu]

Comment: I d not have to do it each time: just enable *Import Maven projects automatically* option in Maven.Import settings.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've hit bug [IDEA-148573](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148573):

> when a Maven dependency uses a classifier, IDEA ignores the classifier when building its classpath and tries to use the non-classified artifact for that dependency